# I'm getting runtime error in this program...why?

Tags: c

A program for merging two words:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    char s1[10],s2[10],s3[10];
    int i,j,n=1;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%s",&s1[i]);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%s",&s2[i]);

    for(j=0;s2[i];j++)
    { 
        s3[i] = s1[i]+s2[j]; 
    } 
    printf("%s",s3); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I'm getting a runtime error in this program. Could anyone help me to correct it or point out what the error is?

Comment: Maybe you can break down the program into smaller parts and try each of them on its own?

Comment: Please, clear up your question! Almost everyone is replying something different and you still give no feedback.

Comment: @Sharme You cannot merge words like this `s3[i] = s1[i]+s2[j];`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
scanf("%s",&s1[i]);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
scanf("%s",&s2[i]);
```

This is not how you read strings. Try this:

```
scanf("%s", s1);
scanf("%s", s2);
```

That's not perfect, but should work for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s",&s1[i]);` does not do what you think it does. It seems to me you are confusing `%s` with `%c`. This is causing a buffer overflow. So read the documentation of `scanf()` format strings.

Then, don't use `scanf()` because it's unsafe and hard to use correctly. For getting user input, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have several problems:

- You are using `scanf` in a wrong a way. It should be like `scanf("%s", s1)`; same for s2.
- To merge two strings you can use built-in function `strcat` which append its second argument to its first argument; just use it two times to merge your two strings in vector `s3`.

In conclusion, your code should look like:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
   char s1[10],s2[10],s3[20];
   scanf("%s",s1);
   scanf("%s",s2);
   strcat(s3,s1);
   strcat(s3,s2);
   printf("%s",s3); 
   printf("\n");
   return 0; 
}
```

Just remember that your `s3` vector must be sufficiently large to contain both your strings.

Comment: but my question is : You are given two words (not necessarily meaningful words) over the lower case English alphabet. They are to be merged into a single new word in which all the letters (including repetitions) in the given two words occur in increasing order (‘a’ is the least and ‘z’ is the largest) from left to right.

Comment: See,i have to merge two words "hello" and "world".but it must not be merged as "helloworld" but in the alphabetic order as "dehllloorw"...For that i have to write the program...I dont know how to write..could you please help me...

Comment: Well, you can merge them in `s3` vector as above and then sort it. You can use for example `qsort()`.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay No vector what? Your answer is exactly what I was suggesting about!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char s1[10], s2[10], s3[20];
    int i, j, n=1;

    scanf("%9s", s1);
    scanf("%9s", s2);

    sprintf(s3, "%s%s", s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n",s3); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing a free online course "Programming, Data Structures & Algorithms" at https://onlinecourses.nptel.ac.in

Anyway, the answer to this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[20], b[10], c;
    int x[20];
    int i,j,l,n,swap;
    scanf("%s",a);
    scanf("%s",b);
    strcat(a,b);
    l=strlen(a);
    for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
        n = a[i];
        x[i] = n;
    }
    for(i=0; i<(l-1); i++) {
        for(j=0; j<(l-i-1); j++) {
            if(x[j]>x[j+1]) {
                swap = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j+1];
                x[j+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<l; i++) {
        c = x[i];
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*You should edit the question if you really meant [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743519/im-gettting-runtime-error-in-this-program-why/22806989#comment34744839_22743648).*

Okay first of all, if you declare like `char arr[10];` then read like `scanf("%s",arr);`

So you read the two words like:

```
scanf("%s",s1);
scanf("%s",s2);
```

Okay, now to merge two words of length `10`, first declare the result array to be twice of `10`.

So here goes the full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(char*)a - *(char*)b );
}

int main()
{
    char s1[10],s2[10],s3[20];

    scanf("%s",s1);
    scanf("%s",s2);

    strcpy(s3,s1); // copies content of s1 to s3
    strcat(s3,s2); // merges to end of s3 the content of s2

    qsort(s3,strlen(s3),sizeof(char),compare); //sorts s3

    printf("%s",s3); 
    return 0;

}
```

See [qsort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).